# Неподдерживаемые символы в SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Какие в SQLite есть неподдерживаемые символы, при попытке вставки которых, вылетает ошибка? У меня выдавал ошибку только пробел, остальных символов пока не заметил.

Comment: Вы уверены что правильно инсертили  в Вашу бд?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, вроде бы да... Ладно, доберусь до проекта и снова перепроверю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что запрещенным является символ `'`, т.к. он используется для обособления строк. Для использования экранируйте его: `\'`

```
yourString.replaceAll("'","\'");
```

И как пишут, проблемы с ASCII STOP и непечатаемыми символами.

А вот с пробелом вряд ли могут быть проблемы.